# Sql Component :Consume multiple rows and mark them all as processed using onConsume

Tags: apache-camel, camel-sql

I configured camel sql component to read data from from database table . I have "onConsume" parameter working when i read one row at a time , but doesn't work when i try to read multiple rows at a time using "maxMessagesPerPoll". Here is what i tried ...

**Working :** When i read one row at a time and update the row using onConsume .

My consumer endpoint uri looks like :

```
sql:select * from REPORT where IS_VIOLATED != 'N' and TYPE = 'Provisioning'?consumer.delay=1000&consumer.onConsume=update REPORT set IS_VIOLATED = 'N' where REPORT_ID =:#REPORT_ID
```

**Not working :** When I configured camel's sql component to read configurable rows(using "maxMessagesPerPoll") . It reads multiple rows at a time but onConsume doesn't seem to work . I tried to tell camel to use IN operator and setting header value(REPORT_ID) with a array of values for IN clause.

My consumer endpoint uri now  looks like :

```
sql:select * from REPORT where IS_VIOLATED != 'N' and TYPE = 'Provisioning'?consumer.delay=1000&maxMessagesPerPoll=3&consumer.useIterator=false&consumer.onConsume=update REPORT set IS_VIOLATED = 'N' where REPORT_ID in(:#REPORT_ID)
```

I might be doing something wrong here. I did enough searching on this already and found related [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39035312/how-to-update-only-consumed-sql-rows-with-apache-camel-sql-component), [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50208286/in-clause-in-apache-camel-2-18?rq=1) . But it doesn't put me on correct path.

I need to be able to mark all the consumed rows to IS_VIOLATED = 'N' .

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

By carefully looking at the [apache sql component doc](http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html) :

I tried implementing custom processing stratergy, using attribute  "processingStrategy"`.

```
public class ReportProcessingStratergy implements SqlProcessingStrategy {
@Override
public int commit(DefaultSqlEndpoint defaultSqlEndpoint, Exchange exchange, Object o, JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, String s) throws Exception {
    s = s.replace("?","5066834,5066835,5066832");
    return jdbcTemplate.update(s);
}

@Override
public int commitBatchComplete(DefaultSqlEndpoint defaultSqlEndpoint, JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, String s) throws Exception {
    return 0;
}
```

}

configure spring bean :

```
  <bean class="go.ga.ns.reconc.sl.ReportProcessingStratergy" id="reportProcessingStratergy">
```

now my sql consumer endpoint uri looks like :

```
sql:select * from REPORT where IS_VIOLATED != 'N' and TYPE = 'Provisioning'?consumer.delay=1000&maxMessagesPerPoll=3&consumer.useIterator=false&&processingStrategy=#reportProcessingStratergy&consumer.onConsume=update REPORT set IS_VIOLATED = 'N' where REPORT_ID in(?)
```

**note** :processingStrategy=#reportProcessingStratergy(# has significance as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265432/implementing-a-custom-process-strategy-with-apache-camel-file-component), it did not work with out it)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you set `consumer.useIterator=false`, and the doc says:

> If true each row returned when polling will be processed individually. If false the entire java.util.List of data is set as the IN body.

So I think that because of this option, the `:#REPORT_ID` is no more understood, since it would be from the entire list and no more from each row.

Maybe removing this option would already be enough.

I also didn't understand why you changed the where clause from `where REPORT_ID =:#REPORT_ID` to `where REPORT_ID in(:#REPORT_ID)`.